# Using Redisearch in Concurrent Requests

Tags: laravel, postgresql, redis, geospatial, redisearch

I have deployed an API using Laravel 8 in M6G 8X Large Server. My System architecture is as follows.

`Client -> NGINX -> PHP-FPM -> Laravel API -> PGBouncer -> PostgreSQL/PostGIS`

The API gets back the result to the client request from a Postgres Function which uses the information from a table of 12 billion records on an average of 300 ms. I did load testing using jmeter for 50K requests with 500 parallel requests for which I have got only a throughput of 390 Requests/Sec.

In order to mitigate this issue I have loaded the 12 billion records in Redis memory and did the same operation of postgres function in Redis using RediSearch FT.Aggregate function with Geospatial filter for which I have got the result on an average of 250-300 ms. I did the same load testing for 50K requests with 400 parallel requests in which I have got only the throughput of 45 Requests/sec which is so worse than the Postgres Function approach.

`Client -> NGINX -> PHP-FPM -> Laravel API -> Redisearch -> Redis`

Please let me know on how to improve the throughput for concurrent requests using Redis Approach as my assumption is there is no lock issue or connection to Postgres DB issue in Redis. Thanks.

**Sample Query**

```
FT.AGGREGATE test_idx "@location:[-84.31455662683010 33.92779720276280 20 mi]" 
APPLY "geodistance(-84.31455662683010,33.92779720276280, @location)" as distance 
APPLY "(@a*(( 20-(@distance/1609.344))/20))" as a1 
APPLY (@a1*@b) as a1b 
APPLY 1 as test 
GROUPBY 1 @test 
    REDUCE SUM 1 @a1 as a_total 
    REDUCE SUM 1 @a1b as a1b_total 
    APPLY (@a_total/(3.14*(20^2))*100) as val_1 
    APPLY (@a1b_total/@a_total) as val_2
```

Comment: How did you deploy Redis/RediSearch? Are you using a cluster? Can you please add a sample query?

Comment: Is this single instance system or multiple instances? If this has multiple instances we want to add all instances in same cluster group

Comment: I have loaded the Redisearch module installed and builded from source in Redis Library. I am not using any cluster. I have edited the question with the sample query.

Comment: This is a single instance system.

Comment: Then I think you have the answer, if you want to scale it you need to run multi shards, Redis scales by Multi process.